# ¿De dónde viene el uso de "viejo" como "los padres de uno"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, españa, sustantivos

Hoy día se puede ver en el DLE la siguiente acepción de *[viejo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bnRGe0W)*:

> 7. m. y f. coloq. Padre y madre de una persona. *¿Lo sabe tu viejo?*

Esta acepción es reciente, dado que en la edición de 1992 esta acepción no aparece. Curiosamente, en la edición de 2001 sí aparece pero marcada como americanismo. Y hablando de americanismos, parece que en multitud de países de Hispanoamérica se usa pero para hablar de casi cualquier persona: "Se usa para dirigirse o referirse afectuosamente a alguien, especialmente al padre, la madre, la pareja o los amigos."

Sin embargo, hablando desde el punto de vista de España, yo la primera vez que oí llamar "viejo" al padre de alguien fue en algún medio audiovisual, no sé si en alguna película o incluso puede que un cómic allá por los años 90. Me llamó mucho la atención y pensé que sería la forma en que se le ocurrió a algún traductor, dado que en inglés sí se suele usar la expresión *[old man](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/old%20man)* para referirse al padre de uno. Imaginé que simplemente el traductor quería reflejar esa forma coloquial de referirse al padre del personaje que fuera.

Así pues, y desde el punto de vista de España, ¿cuándo se empezó a usar aquí la palabra "viejo" para referirse a los padres de alguien? ¿Fue por influencia directa del inglés a través de traducciones de cómics/series/películas/libros o lo que fuera? ¿O pudo ser por influencia del uso similar en Hispanoamérica?

Comment: ¿Cuándo lo oiste por primera vez porque yo lo decía de chaval bastante y en mi entorno se usaba mucho? Y aunque era más cosa de jovenes también gente mayor lo decía a veces, así que supongo que viene de lejos.

Comment: @blonfu pues no sé exactamente cuándo, pero pongamos por los años 90 (lo he añadido a la pregunta). También es posible que fuera una expresión que se extendiera gradualmente por España, o que simplemente yo no la oí hasta esa época pero se usara de antes. En todo caso, eso es lo que me interesa saber, cuándo y cómo entró en España esa expresión.

Comment: ¿Recién en 2001 aparece? En Argentina la forma habitual para referirse a los padres de uno es *mis viejos* (o *los viejos* si uno habla con un hermano). Esto es así desde que recuerdo y mis viejos también hablan así para referirse a los suyos. :)

Comment: ["Mi viejo"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mi_viejo), del argentino Piero, es de 1969. Acá en el cono sur es una canción requete conocida.

Comment: @pablodf76 y Rodrigo: la pregunta parece hacer referencia exclusivamente a **España**

Answer (score 1):

Te diría que por dos razones: los dibujos animados y series, y la tónica macarra y rebelde de los 90.

Los *Simpson*, entre otros, cuando Bart llama "viejo" a su padre. Las traducciones de Latinoamérica que llegan a España, como *Scooby Doo*, pueden ser ejemplos de normalización de su uso. *El príncipe de Bel Air*, y una cantidad de series americanas de los 90 propiciaron su uso, yo creo.

A eso le sumas el ambiente de los 90, *et voilà*.

Si te fijas hoy en día apenas se usa.

Comment: La canción "mi viejo" es de 1975. O sea que no puede ser que venga de Los Simpsons o de los 90's.